# ngOninit variable is not binding in html angular 4

Tags: javascript, html, angular

working on google map, able to display the map, I want to display the current location but its not displaying

```
     export class AppComponent {
      title = '';

      ngOnInit() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (p) {
              var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.coords.latitude, p.coords.longitude);

              console.log(p.coords.latitude);
              console.log(p.coords.longitude);

              var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

             if (geocoder) {
            geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': LatLng}, function (results, status) {
           if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
             console.log(results[0].formatted_address);
                 this.title = results[0].formatted_address;
                 console.log(this.title);
                 }
           else {
            console.log("Geocoding failed: " + status);
           }
        });
      }
    });
      } else {
          alert('Geo Location feature is not supported in this browser.');
      }

}
```

Here "this.title", i am getting the current location

HTML code

```
<h1> The Title is: {{title}}</h1>
```

in Console i am able to see the title value , why  it is not binding in html?

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: Your component lacks `implements OnInit`

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ TypeScript makes interfaces null and void during runtime so it's not actually needed. Javascript does not have a concept of interfaces.

Comment: @JamieRees Sure. But if you want to compile/transpile you have to put the `implements`.

Comment: Try using `AfterViewInit` or even `AfterContentInit` instead of `OnInit` maybe the component there isn't yet initialized while you in OnInit

Comment: Try to inject ChangeDetectorRef and call detectChanges()

Comment: No erros in console,  tried with  implements OnInit,AfterViewInit ,AfterContentInit  didnt worked.

Comment: use arrow functions instead of function(...)

Comment: @Vishnu what is logged in `console.log(this.title);` inside the function

Comment: current address i am getting , not  able to  display in html  by binding {{title}}

Comment: use `.bind(this)` end of the function now will try to binding `{{title}}` in html

Comment: declare title like `private title: string;`

Comment: Tried both not working!

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ No, you absolutely do not have to write it. It's recommended, but not required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the variable `title` declared in the scope of `AppComponent` class, inside the scope of the callback function inside `geocode`. You must access title with with its' original scope.

The trick is to store `this` into a variable, which in this case is the scope of *AppComponent*

```
export class AppComponent {
    title = '';
    var self = this;
    ......
}
```

And then use it inside any callback functions. Here in your case, it is the callback function inside *geocode* call

```
geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': LatLng}, function (results, status) {
   if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
       console.log(results[0].formatted_address);
       self.title = results[0].formatted_address; //Here we are using self, as the original context of title
       console.log(this.title);
   }
   else {
       console.log("Geocoding failed: " + status);
   }
});
```

Answer is also provided here in another question [this-becomes-null](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47766040/8438534)

Comment: After the page refresh  that model (title) value is  getting cleared !!!

Comment: does your ngOnInit gets called again after page refresh? If it does, then check if the title setter code block gets hit inside the if checks