# this becomes null inside the javascript function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have java script function which gives current lat long  inside that function making an http  post call like this "this.http.post" but the value of  this null inside the function

My code

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(p) {
          var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.coords.latitude, p.coords.longitude);
          console.log(p.coords.latitude);
          console.log(p.coords.longitude);
          var dataObj = {
            latitude: p.coords.latitude,
            longitude: p.coords.longitude
          };
          this.http.post('https://XXXXX/datacenteres.php', {
              dataObj
            })
            .subscribe(
              res => {
                console.log(res);
              },
              err => {
                console.log("Error occured");
              }
            );
        }
      }
    }
```

I am getting this errors in the console "Cannot read property 'http' of null".

Inside navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (p) { this is null  }

Inside the If statement i am able to get the "this".

Comment: Did you try using an arrow function?

Comment: dont know about arrow functions..inside the post arrow function is there

Comment: can you provide example code

Comment: navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((p)  => { // function code here })

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this :

use `.bind(this)` end of the function

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(p) {
            var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.coords.latitude, p.coords.longitude);

            console.log(p.coords.latitude);
            console.log(p.coords.longitude);

            var dataObj = {
                latitude: p.coords.latitude,
                longitude: p.coords.longitude
            };
            this.http.post('https://XXXXX/datacenteres.php', {
                dataObj
            }).subscribe(res => {
                console.log(res);
            }, err => {
                console.log("Error occured");
            });
        }.bind(this));

    }
}
```

Comment: its working!!!  please check my other question i didnt got any corrrect answer check with this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47752644/ngoninit-variable-is-not-binding-in-html-angular-4?noredirect=1#comment82466633_47752644

Comment: ya !! your answer is useful for me !!

Answer (score 4):

You can use arrow function like below:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(p => {
        //var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.coords.latitude, p.coords.longitude);
        console.log(p.coords.latitude);
        console.log(p.coords.longitude);
        var dataObj = {
          latitude :p.coords.latitude,
          longitude:p.coords.longitude
        };
        this.http.post('https://XXXXX/datacenteres.php', {
          dataObj
        })
          .subscribe(
            res => {
              console.log(res);
            },
            err => {
              console.log("Error occured");
            }
          );
      })
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply store `this` into a variable and use it inside the callback function. Its' quite handy

```
ngOnInit():void {
var self = this;
if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (p) {
          var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.coords.latitude, p.coords.longitude);

          console.log(p.coords.latitude);
          console.log(p.coords.longitude);

            var dataObj = {
                latitude :p.coords.latitude,
                longitude:p.coords.longitude
                        };
          self.http.post('https://XXXXX/datacenteres.php', {
    dataObj
    })
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          console.log(res);
        },
        err => {
          console.log("Error occured");
        }
      );

  }
  }

}
```

Comment: you solved my other question too!!! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47752644/ngoninit-variable-is-not-binding-in-html-angular-4?noredirect=1#comment82493463_47752644  ..

Comment: Great!! Have posted link of this answer there as well. Could you please accept this answer in that question then?